# Rails and bash_profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I've just added highligh to my terminal in mac os editing the .bash_profile and adding this:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
```

and after doing that rails started to fail, I can't run "rails c" nor "rails s", I'm sure it's related with this change, maybe I deleted something else...

My .bash_profile just has those two lines I showed there...

Any Idea?

Comment: What do the logs say when you run 'rails c' or 'rails s'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess: Are you sure you didnt erase former contents of `.bash_profile` by mistake?